# Porting j_security_check from JBOSS to Websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, jboss5.x, j-security-check

I am using `j_security_check` for my struts web project and i am deploying it in jboss.

In my `web.xml` i have defined role `testuser`, created a jar file which contains `users.properties` and `roles.properties` with jar name as `TestUserInfo.jar` where `Test` is the name of the application.

My `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>To secure Test site</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>test_actions</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>testuser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>test offshore realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login_form.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login_error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>testuser</role-name>
</security-role>
```

`users.properties` file have `username=password` as name value pair and `roles.properties` will have `username=role` (in my case `user=testuser`) as name value pair.

I am able to login using the username and password as it is in `users.properties` file when application is deployed in JBoss. `TestUserInfo.jar` is kept under `jboss-5.1.0.GA\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\lib`.

What i have to do in websphere for implementing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a 'file based custom user registry'. Following link gives details on how to configure it (users.props and groups.props files in this example will contain same information  as in your users.properties and roles.properties files). The link is for WAS v6. If you're using another version you may search infocenter for same concept on your version.

[Configuring custom user registries](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftsec_tdaman.html)

Comment: Thanks.. Will i require to change any code in my Java struts application ??

Comment: No further change shall be necessary, as you are using standard declerative security.

Comment: Can u help me what all changes i have to make in J2ee application ?? Any Link??

Comment: You don't have to change anything in the application. Only server configuration is necessary; following 13 steps in the above link shall be enough.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere supports a number of registries and these days a federated repository is the norm in WAS.

The federated repository can be made up of file based (a file in the File System where user/password, groups etc are stored, LDAP Server, databases etc.

At the end of the day, user information is stored in some registry. JBoss/tomcat keeps them in different files (like the names that you mentioned) and also supports LDAP and possibly other user registries. Similiarly WAS supports multiple such user registries.

You pick and choose what is the best one for your environment.

Have a read at this to get a good understanding this space

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0701_ilechko/0701_ilechko.html

In short, if you want to store your users, the simplest and easiest choice would be **fileRegistry.xml**